# Asynctask still buttons are hiding depends on the value

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I'm creating an app that displays a list of objects. I had an error handling wherein if the value is less than or equal to 10, next and previous button will be hidden but when i search a value that has more than 10, next and previous button are still hidden

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    btnback2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    btnnext2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    if (GetSearchValue.size() <= 10) {
        btnback2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnnext2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    btnback2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View convertView) {
            new ValueBack2().execute();
        }
    });
    btnnext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View convertView) {
            new ValueNext2().execute();
        }
    });

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Asycdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Cross check the value of GetSearchInfo.size()...print it in the log

Comment: Are you sure that the size of `GetSearchValue` is more than 10 ? debug and make sure .. if the problem still exists , check your xml and make sure you didn't set visibility of the buttons to 'invisible' or 'gone'

Comment: @NayraAhmed the button is still hidden because i limit the display to 10 but i thought that when i use .size(), total result will be read. But it only read the list in the listview.

Comment: do you have an idea how to get the total result instead of the total display in listview? @NayraAhmed sorry beginner only in android

Comment: when you make your search you get the search results in an array, that array should have all the results unless you get only 10 results.
so limit the display to 10 not the search results.

Comment: Try `Marcin Orlowski`'s answer. I think, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you do subsequent search therefore so you need to show these widgets when needed as they are hidden by previous search.

```
btnback2.setVisibility((GetSearchValue.size() <= 10) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
btnnext2.setVisibility((GetSearchValue.size() <= 10) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Why you bind `onClickListenrs` in `onPostExecute()` instead in `onCreate()`? This is not proper approach (and quite pointless)

Also, you do not need to call `super.onPostExecute()` - there's nothing in super class by design.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:-

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

  btnback2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
  btnnext2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
  btnback2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  btnnext2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  if (GetSearchValue.size() <= 10){
                      btnback2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                      btnnext2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }

  btnback2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View convertView) {
          new ValueBack2().execute();
      }
  });

  btnnext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View convertView) {
          new ValueNext2().execute();
      }
  });

  super.onPostExecute(result);
  Asycdialog.dismiss();
}
```